# How to use SQL Select Query in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have one query of `SQL`, which I want to put in a `VBA` code to bring result in Excel sheet.

I tried the code pasted below.

```
Sub Connect2SQLXpress()

Dim Ors As Object Dim oCon As Object

Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set Ors = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection oCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
   oCon.Open
Ors.Source = "Select KeyInstn,LongName,Shortname,Shortestname From New_inst WHERE ......" 

Ors.Open Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Ors
Ors.Close oCon.Close

If Not Ors Is Nothing Then Set Ors = Nothing 
If Not oCon Is Nothing Then Set oCon = Nothing
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out that what is going wrong ??

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Well, it would help a great deal if you told us what wasn't working. You haven't indicated what the problem is yet. "Here's some code. What's wrong?" doesn't describe the problem very clearly. Can you [edit] your question and add some information about what the actual issue is you're having? (It will be useful for people who are trying to find an answer to a similar problem in the future.) Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: from looking at it I'm guessing the SQL Query is wrong, and the Connection string is wrong (no database or server!)

Comment: @user2563891: For help on opeing ADO Connections, take a look at [MSDN Library: Connecting to a SQL Server Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905872(v=sql.80).aspx) and [W3Schools: ADO Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/)

Comment: @Philip: The poster is asking for help here; we shouldn't have to *guess* what the problem is they want our help with, when they have that information. It also doesn't do any good for future readers here when searching, because the search engine can't *guess* at what the question is about. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: that's true, but I can see just by looking at his code that his connection string is wrong for OLE DB SQL Server connections, and his SQL Query is wrong too, so I gave him a few pointers

Comment: @Philip: That you can see it by looking doesn't improve the use in a search later, and giving the answer before the question is edited removes the incentive to edit (especially for new users that often just post once, get an answer, and then move on).

Answer (score 0):

to create a good connection string try this:

1. Right-click on your desktop (or any folder)
2. choose New > textfile
3. Right-click on the file you have created, and change it's name (**AND EXTENSION**) to *ConnectionInfo.UDL*
4. Double-click on the file **ConnectionInfo.UDL** and this should open in Microsoft data - Core Services.
5. Set your *Provider*, *ServerName*, and *Database* then click **Test Connection** before clicking
6. Right-click on the file, and this time choose to Open it with **Notepad**
7. You should see a proper OLE DB Connection string, that you can copy into your VB Code.

After that, you need to ensure your SELECT Query is correct, by running it in SQL Server Management Services or whatever to see that you get results.

Once you have a recordset open in Excel, you could use the **CopyFromRecordset** method of the *range* object to dump your recordset into Excel

Comment: @user2563891: if I solved your problem, please mark it as an answer by clicking the green check mark under the vote counter to the left of my answer.